# No CORS error when making GET requests, but CORS error when making POST requests

Tags: node.js, reactjs, post, get, cors

I have a Node/Express server that interacts with a React app.

I need to make POST and GET requests, the problem is that when making POST requests I get a CORS error, the usual:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:9000/testAPI' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I specified on the response on the server the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, but I am not sure if I have to set this header for a POST request as well. And if I do, what domain should it specify?

I am also not willing to use hacks like CORS extensions, or npm packages. I want to use CORS.

The server-side looks like so:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.url);

    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000");
    res.send("API is working properly");
});

module.exports = router;
```

In the React app, the GET request looks like so (works just fine):

```
const res = await fetch('http://localhost:9000/testAPI');

console.log(res);
```

The POST request looks like so (CORS error thrown):

```
const res = await fetch('http://localhost:9000/testAPI', {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'cors',
    cache: 'no-cache',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ someData: "POST requests are working properly" })
});
```

Do I need to specify some additional headers or properties on the POST request? Or do I have to modify something on the server-side?

**If I will not have this problem when going live, than I do not mind using a hack like CORS extension.**

Comment: set header for a POST request as well and use same port   localhost:9000  localhost:3000 is different origin

Comment: I'm hoping I did it right: ```const res = await fetch('http://localhost:9000/testAPI', { 
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'cors',
        cache: 'no-cache',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:9000'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ someData: "POST requests are working properly" })
      });```. Did not work sadly. Please tell me if you wanted me to do something else.

Comment: Try `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' `

Comment: Didn't work. Thanks tho

Comment: @LucianAnghel First things first: make sure you read and understand https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: @LucianAnghel You must implement a CORS policy on the server side that allows your frontend's origin with method `POST` and request header `Content-Type`. Check out http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

Comment: @LucianAnghel   Like above said,  set 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' in server side, not client side. CROS setup is for server restriction.  You need server allow http://localhost:9000 to make request to your server. If you want allow all origin, just set 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' in  server side.

Answer (score 2):

You may use this package [cors](https://github.com/expressjs/cors)

```
// Install
npm install cors
yarn add cors
```

```js
    // server.js 
    const express = require('express');
    const cors = require('cors');
    const app = express();
    
    // global middleware
    app.use(cors());
    // You can use route based middleware too
    router.post("/", cors(), (req, res, next) => {
     // process request & send response to client
    });
```